# Using angular ng-repeat for multi-dimentional array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm currently working on a game and am trying to use NG repeat to dynamically add divs depending on how many latter and words there are. so for example if the answer to a queston in the game was "Clean Sheet" then i would want NG-Repeat to make the correct amount of columns so that it would say __ __ __ __ __  space   __ __ __ __ __ then the user can fill them. Ive currently wrote this :

```
try{
//in this example presume $stateParams.answer is "clean sheet"

var answerArr = $stateParams.answer.toString().split(' ');
var finalLines = "";
$scope.mainWordHolder = [];

angular.forEach(answerArr, function(value, key) {
     var amt = value.length;

     $scope.amtofLetters=[];
      for (var i=0; i<amt; i++) {
          $scope.amtofLetters.push(i);
      }
      $scope.mainWordHolder.push($scope.amtofLetters);
      $scope.amtofLetters = [];
});

console.log($scope.mainWordHolder);
}catch(e){console.log("error : "+ e);}
```

at this point my $scope.mainWordHolder is :

```
[ [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ], [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ] ]
```

which is exactly what i want so i know how many letters are needed for each word. How can i use ng-repeat to show this as divs so that i can create a keyboard and the user can enter keys  like other popular games.

Ive tried this :

```
<div class="row">
<div ng-repeat="content in answerArr" class="col"> 
       <div ng-repeat="contentt in mainWordHolder" class="col">

      </div>   
</div>
</div>
```

but i get nothing for some reason. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to reference `answerArr` in your `ng-repeat`, but `answerArr` is not stored on the scope.

When you use `ng-repeat="content in answerArr"`, `answerArr` needs to be stored on the scope to be accessible in the HTML.

Try storing `answerArr` on your scope to be able to access it's contents via `ng-repeat`.

Comment: Thanks i missed that

Comment: its just listing them now as rows rather than _ _ _ _ _   _ _ _ _ _

Comment: Can you update the question with the current state of your code? It's hard to figure out the problem if any changes have been made.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the 'content' which represents the array in the whole array (the outer). Try this :

```
<div class="row">
<div ng-repeat="content in answerArr" class="col"> 
       <div ng-repeat="contentt in content" class="col">

      </div>   
</div>
</div>
```